# Program file is not found when attempting to start it

Tags: raspbian-buster

I installed the Liberica JDK on my Raspberry Pi 4 with Buster, by downloading the tar.gz, expanding it to /opt/ and the executing the script below:

```
#! /bin/sh

JAVA_PATH="/opt/LibericaJDK/jdk-11.0.7/bin"

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" $JAVA_PATH/java 1
sudo update-alternatives --set "java" $JAVA_PATH/java
```

The script runs without an error, calling `java -version` returned the message

```
No such file or directory
```

Ok, the German version of the message ("Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden"), but with the same meaning.

Same when I do

```
cd /opt/LibericaJDK/jdk-11.0.7/bin
./java -version
```

or

```
/opt/LibericaJDK/jdk-11.0.7/bin/java -version
```

I can see the file when I run `ls`, I can `cat` the file (although that does not make much sense …), I can copy, move and rename it, but I cannot execute it (and yes, the X flag is set!! For user, group, and others!!):

```
ls -la java
-rwxrwxr-x 1 pi pi 13512 Apr 10 20:01 java
```

Same for all other programs of the JDK.

The output of `strace java` from the home directory:

```
strace java -version
execve("/usr/bin/java", ["java", "-version"], 0xffcaeaf0 /* 24 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
strace: exec: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

After I moved to the installation folder:

```
strace ./java -version
execve("./java", ["./java", "-version"], 0xffcee120 /* 25 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
strace: exec: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

When called with the full path:

```
strace /opt/LibericaJDK/jdk-11.0.7/bin/java -version
execve("/opt/LibericaJDK/jdk-11.0.7/bin/java", ["/opt/LibericaJDK/jdk-11.0.7/bin/"..., "-version"], 0xffa27660 /* 25 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
strace: exec: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

I am running the Raspberry Pi in 64-bit mode, I downloaded the aarch64 version of the JDK. I restarted the machine several times already …

The banner after login through ssh says:

```
Linux Raspi04 4.19.97-v8+ #1294 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 30 13:27:08 GMT 2020 aarch64
```

The output of `readelf -a ./java` is:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           AArch64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0xd58
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          11656 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         8
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         29
  Section header string table index: 28

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         0000000000000200  00000200
       000000000000001b  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             000000000000021c  0000021c
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 3] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE             000000000000023c  0000023c
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 4] .hash             HASH             0000000000000260  00000260
       0000000000000100  0000000000000004   A       5     0     8
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM           0000000000000360  00000360
       00000000000002b8  0000000000000018   A       6     3     8
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB           0000000000000618  00000618
       00000000000001a5  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM           00000000000007be  000007be
       000000000000003a  0000000000000002   A       5     0     2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED          00000000000007f8  000007f8
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       6     1     8
  [ 9] .rela.dyn         RELA             0000000000000818  00000818
       0000000000000108  0000000000000018   A       5     0     8
  [10] .rela.plt         RELA             0000000000000920  00000920
       0000000000000150  0000000000000018  AI       5    21     8
  [11] .init             PROGBITS         0000000000000a70  00000a70
       0000000000000014  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS         0000000000000a90  00000a90
       0000000000000100  0000000000000010  AX       0     0     16
  [13] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000000b90  00000b90
       0000000000000354  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     8
  [14] .fini             PROGBITS         0000000000000ee4  00000ee4
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [15] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000000ef8  00000ef8
       0000000000000090  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [16] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         0000000000000f88  00000f88
       0000000000000004  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [17] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY       0000000000011d78  00001d78
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [18] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY       0000000000011d80  00001d80
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [19] .dynamic          DYNAMIC          0000000000011d88  00001d88
       0000000000000220  0000000000000010  WA       6     0     8
  [20] .got              PROGBITS         0000000000011fa8  00001fa8
       0000000000000040  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [21] .got.plt          PROGBITS         0000000000011fe8  00001fe8
       0000000000000088  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [22] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000012070  00002070
       0000000000000018  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [23] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000012088  00002088
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [24] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00002088
       0000000000000074  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [25] .gnu_debuglink    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000020fc
       0000000000000014  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [26] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00002110
       00000000000008b8  0000000000000018          27    61     8
  [27] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  000029c8
       00000000000002be  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [28] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  00002c86
       0000000000000100  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040
                 0x00000000000001c0 0x00000000000001c0  R E    0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000000200
                 0x000000000000001b 0x000000000000001b  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000f8c 0x0000000000000f8c  R E    0x10000
  LOAD           0x0000000000001d78 0x0000000000011d78 0x0000000000011d78
                 0x0000000000000310 0x0000000000000318  RW     0x10000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000001d88 0x0000000000011d88 0x0000000000011d88
                 0x0000000000000220 0x0000000000000220  RW     0x8
  NOTE           0x000000000000021c 0x000000000000021c 0x000000000000021c
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000001d78 0x0000000000011d78 0x0000000000011d78
                 0x0000000000000288 0x0000000000000288  R      0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame 
   03     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     
   07     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got 

Dynamic section at offset 0x1d88 contains 30 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libjli.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [$ORIGIN/../lib/jli:$ORIGIN/../lib]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0xa70
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0xee4
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x11d78
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x11d80
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000004 (HASH)               0x260
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x618
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x360
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              421 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x11fe8
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           336 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x920
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x818
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             264 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: PIE
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x7f8
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         1
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x7be
 0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          7
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0

Relocation section '.rela.dyn' at offset 0x818 contains 11 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000011d78  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    e58
000000011d80  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    e10
000000011fb0  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    ee0
000000011fd0  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    e60
000000011fd8  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    b90
000000012078  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    12078
000000012080  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    f80
000000011fb8  000300000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 _ITM_deregisterTMClone + 0
000000011fc0  000600000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.17 + 0
000000011fc8  000e00000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 __gmon_start__ + 0
000000011fe0  001a00000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 _ITM_registerTMCloneTa + 0

Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x920 contains 14 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000012000  000400000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 JLI_Launch + 0
000000012008  000600000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.17 + 0
000000012010  000900000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 JLI_StringDup + 0
000000012018  000c00000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.17 + 0
000000012020  000d00000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 JLI_List_add + 0
000000012028  000e00000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 __gmon_start__ + 0
000000012030  000f00000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 abort@GLIBC_2.17 + 0
000000012038  001000000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 JLI_PreprocessArg + 0
000000012040  001200000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 JLI_InitArgProcessing + 0
000000012048  001500000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 JLI_List_new + 0
000000012050  001700000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 JLI_MemFree + 0
000000012058  001800000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 JLI_ReportMessage + 0
000000012060  001900000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 JLI_AddArgsFromEnvVar + 0
000000012068  001b00000402 R_AARCH64_JUMP_SL 0000000000000000 getenv@GLIBC_2.17 + 0

The decoding of unwind sections for machine type AArch64 is not currently supported.

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 29 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000a70     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 
     2: 0000000000012070     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   22 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTab
     4: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_Launch
     5: 0000000000012088     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __bss_start__
     6: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.17 (2)
     7: 0000000000012090     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 _bss_end__
     8: 0000000000012088     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   22 _edata
     9: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_StringDup
    10: 0000000000000ee4     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 _fini
    11: 0000000000012090     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __bss_end__
    12: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.17 (2)
    13: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_List_add
    14: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
    15: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND abort@GLIBC_2.17 (2)
    16: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_PreprocessArg
    17: 0000000000012090     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 _end
    18: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_InitArgProcessing
    19: 0000000000012090     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __end__
    20: 0000000000012088     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __bss_start
    21: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_List_new
    22: 0000000000000b90   456 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 main
    23: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_MemFree
    24: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_ReportMessage
    25: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_AddArgsFromEnvVar
    26: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
    27: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND getenv@GLIBC_2.17 (2)
    28: 0000000000000a70     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 _init

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 93 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 000000000000021c     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 $d
     2: 0000000000000d58     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 $x
     3: 0000000000000ef8     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 $d
     4: 0000000000000d90     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 $x
     5: 0000000000000d90    20 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 call_weak_fn
     6: 0000000000000a70     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 $x
     7: 0000000000000ee4     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 $x
     8: 0000000000000a7c     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 $x
     9: 0000000000000eec     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 $x
    10: 0000000000000b90     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 $x
    11: 0000000000012080     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   22 $d
    12: 0000000000012080     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   22 const_jargs
    13: 0000000000000f00     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 $d
    14: 0000000000000da8     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 $x
    15: 0000000000000da8     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 deregister_tm_clones
    16: 0000000000000dd8     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 register_tm_clones
    17: 0000000000012078     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   22 $d
    18: 0000000000000e10     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 __do_global_dtors_aux
    19: 0000000000012088     1 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   23 completed.7804
    20: 0000000000011d80     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   18 $d
    21: 0000000000011d80     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   18 __do_global_dtors_aux_fin
    22: 0000000000000e58     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 frame_dummy
    23: 0000000000011d78     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 $d
    24: 0000000000011d78     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 __frame_dummy_init_array_
    25: 0000000000012088     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   23 $d
    26: 0000000000000e60     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 $x
    27: 0000000000000f88     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 $d
    28: 0000000000000f88     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 __FRAME_END__
    29: 0000000000000ee0     4 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 __libc_csu_fini
    30: 0000000000011d80     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 __init_array_end
    31: 0000000000000e60   128 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 __libc_csu_init
    32: 0000000000011d88     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS _DYNAMIC
    33: 0000000000011d78     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 __init_array_start
    34: 0000000000011fa8     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
    35: 0000000000000a90     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   12 $x
    36: 0000000000000200     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
    37: 000000000000021c     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
    38: 000000000000023c     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
    39: 0000000000000260     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
    40: 0000000000000360     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 
    41: 0000000000000618     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 
    42: 00000000000007be     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7 
    43: 00000000000007f8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    8 
    44: 0000000000000818     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    9 
    45: 0000000000000920     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   10 
    46: 0000000000000a70     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 
    47: 0000000000000a90     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   12 
    48: 0000000000000b90     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 
    49: 0000000000000ee4     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 
    50: 0000000000000ef8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 
    51: 0000000000000f88     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 
    52: 0000000000011d78     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 
    53: 0000000000011d80     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   18 
    54: 0000000000011d88     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   19 
    55: 0000000000011fa8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   20 
    56: 0000000000011fe8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   21 
    57: 0000000000012070     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   22 
    58: 0000000000012088     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   23 
    59: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   24 
    60: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   25 
    61: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTab
    62: 0000000000012070     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT   22 data_start
    63: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_Launch
    64: 0000000000012088     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __bss_start__
    65: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.1
    66: 0000000000012090     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 _bss_end__
    67: 0000000000012088     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   22 _edata
    68: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_StringDup
    69: 0000000000000ee4     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 _fini
    70: 0000000000012090     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __bss_end__
    71: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_
    72: 0000000000012070     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   22 __data_start
    73: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_List_add
    74: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
    75: 0000000000012078     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL HIDDEN    22 __dso_handle
    76: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND abort@@GLIBC_2.17
    77: 0000000000000ef8     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 _IO_stdin_used
    78: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_PreprocessArg
    79: 0000000000012090     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 _end
    80: 0000000000000d58     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _start
    81: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_InitArgProcessing
    82: 0000000000012090     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __end__
    83: 0000000000012088     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __bss_start
    84: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_List_new
    85: 0000000000000b90   456 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 main
    86: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_MemFree
    87: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_ReportMessage
    88: 0000000000012088     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL HIDDEN    22 __TMC_END__
    89: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND JLI_AddArgsFromEnvVar
    90: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
    91: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND getenv@@GLIBC_2.17
    92: 0000000000000a70     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 _init

Histogram for bucket list length (total of 33 buckets):
 Length  Number     % of total  Coverage
      0  12         ( 36.4%)
      1  16         ( 48.5%)     61.5%
      2  5          ( 15.2%)    100.0%

Version symbols section '.gnu.version' contains 29 entries:
 Addr: 00000000000007be  Offset: 0x0007be  Link: 5 (.dynsym)
  000:   0 (*local*)       0 (*local*)       0 (*local*)       0 (*local*)    
  004:   0 (*local*)       1 (*global*)      2 (GLIBC_2.17)    1 (*global*)   
  008:   1 (*global*)      0 (*local*)       1 (*global*)      1 (*global*)   
  00c:   2 (GLIBC_2.17)    0 (*local*)       0 (*local*)       2 (GLIBC_2.17) 
  010:   0 (*local*)       1 (*global*)      0 (*local*)       1 (*global*)   
  014:   1 (*global*)      0 (*local*)       1 (*global*)      0 (*local*)    
  018:   0 (*local*)       0 (*local*)       0 (*local*)       2 (GLIBC_2.17) 
  01c:   1 (*global*)   

Version needs section '.gnu.version_r' contains 1 entry:
 Addr: 0x00000000000007f8  Offset: 0x0007f8  Link: 6 (.dynstr)
  000000: Version: 1  File: libc.so.6  Cnt: 1
  0x0010:   Name: GLIBC_2.17  Flags: none  Version: 2

Displaying notes found in: .note.ABI-tag
  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000010   NT_GNU_ABI_TAG (ABI version tag)
    OS: Linux, ABI: 3.7.0

Displaying notes found in: .note.gnu.build-id
  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000014   NT_GNU_BUILD_ID (unique build ID bitstring)
    Build ID: 513b2952d0f473880c87ca35df57ee178539ebad
```

Any idea?

Can it be specific to this software??

Comment: What happens when you try to execute  the program , you have only this 'error' : `No such file or directory` ? Maybe use `strace java` for more debug infos ?

Comment: @Ephemeral: The result of `strace java` looks the same for me as when `java` called directly.

Comment: ok and what `readelf -a ./java` say ? You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716702/no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-executing-a-binary)

Comment: @Ephemeral: I added the full output for `readelf -a ./java` to the question.

Comment: Meanwhile, I installed libc6-arm64-cross that contains `ld-linux-aarch64.so.1` (missing before, but that does not make a difference).